# Creating hierarchical properties files with spring boot

Tags: spring, properties

We have a project that contains three resources files - `application-dev.properties` `application-test.properties` and `application-prod.properties`. We have an environment variable that sets the name of the environment we're in and then we load the right property file using computed placeholder as followed:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${environment}.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}
```

I wish to add a new file `application-defaults.properties` that will have all the default properties and only proerties that appear in `application-${environment}.properties` would be overrided by the specific environment property. I tried to do it as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-defaults.properties", "classpath:application-${environment}.properties"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}
```

Thing is, the properties from the defaults file always "win" and take precedence while I want them to be overridden in case the property appears in the specified environment variable. I tried switching the order between them, but still it stays the same. I even tried to change the name of the defaults file to `default.properties` just in order to understand whether the loading order is lexicographic or something like that, but still - the `default.properties` always win.

Note: In order to load the app we use spring-boot.

Comment: You are shure that the property `${environment}` is resolved correctly at the time it is loaded?

Answer (score 6):

If you want multilevel hierarchical profile you can use spring.profiles.include property.

each profile in first level extend properties from application.properties and in second level you can set spring.profiles.include in first line to extend from first level.

for example:

- default profile:

  - application.proerties
- first level profile:

  - application-dev.properties
  - application-prod.properties
- second level profile:

  - application-prod-aws.properties
  - application-prod-azure.properties
  - application-prod-openshift.properties

Answer (score 4):

You can do without the use of placeholders

In `application.properties` specify properties that will be common to all profiles.
In `application-xxx.properties` specify properties for a particular profile.

Then activate profile by `spring.profiles.active: xxx` in `application.properties` or add JVM argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=xxx`

A property declared in `application-xxx.properties` will be priority over a property declared in `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Properties are hierarchical in Spring Boot, bellow how to achieve what you want to do :

```
application.properties (or application.yml) #this file contains all default properties 
application-dev.properties (or application-dev.yml) #contains dev properties and can override properties in application.yml
application-prod.properties (or application-prod.yml) #same as above
```

Personnally I prefer .yml extension which make avoiding redundancy.